# How to view process output with PID ? (proc_open)

Tags: php, python, popen, pcntl, proc-open

edited:

## goal:

I have an application written in Python that can download videos from web pages! (auto detect video link in youtube or other video site)

When I run it in CMD , Runs well and shows the download speed and remined time.

Now I want to make a video downloader site.(LIKE https://dredown.com).
Users enter page link to site.

Wait for it to download.

I want to see the speed and download time.

## Question:

I've used the proc_open  and I run the command

For example, continuously ping

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -t
```

Pid value gained by using the 
    proc_get_status function

```
for example PID=4521
```

after one hours i want see output again  !!! (because The process is still running)

## Is is possible:

(pipe to process with PID) or (recreate the resource with the only id)

function like this : pcntl_waitpid($pid)
that give pid and control it !
i want see output only !

Comment: Why not run the process in the background using `tmux` or `screen`, then attach to it again later when you want to see the output again?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I have an application written in Python that can download videos from web pages! (auto detect video link in youtube or other video site)....
When I run it in CMD , Runs well and shows the download speed and remined time.....
Now I want to make a video downloader site.(LIKE dredown.com)....
Users enter page link to site.....
Wait for it to download....
I want to see the speed and download time....